# Can we have a "Migrate to WordPress StackExchange" option?

Tags: feature-request

- [This question](https://serverfault.com/questions/246784/file-permission-set-to-644-and-wordpress-cannot-access-them) got me to thinking about the need.
- [This search](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/wordpress) shows a non trivial amount of chatter about WordPress. A very rough estimate of questions that are specific to WordPress and not just mentioning WP as an incidental seems to be maybe a little less than half.
- We have [250 questions marked with the WordPress tag](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/wordpress) and 6 with [WordPress-mu](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/wordpress-mu)

Seems like we should be thinking about adding the ability to migrate there rather than commenting for people to move their own question.

**EDIT:**
It seems that flagging questions for migration is how to deal with it now. Has that become the standard procedure for migrations to other sites that aren't yet on the voting list? It seemed (and still seems) terribly inefficient and even moderator-unfriendly to be flagging questions like that. Once it annoys enough mods, it'll get added as a feature?

Comment: Aside but, you/someone could kill the [wordpress-mu] tag.  Wordpress-mu is depreciated as its functionality is now part of the Wordpress core.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is one. You flag for mod attention and tell us that it "belongs on WP" and one of us will move it there if appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

Mark has the right idea.

What's more, if you all keep doing that, it'll get noticed and the possibility of adding a 5th migration starts getting discussed at the dev-level. When I have time again (not likely for another week or more) I intend to go delving into mod-tools and get another migration-chart like I did before. See what's getting migrated where.