# Can we have more "Suggested Sites" for question migrations?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, migration

Are we able to add more options into the "belongs on" menu within the flag menu?

I'm aware of the "flag for moderator approval" as discussed in [this](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/1324/can-we-have-a-migrate-to-wordpress-stackexchange-option) Meta question, but I'm wondering if some more frequently-used migrations would be good to add - it may help curb having inappropriate questions closed.

Comment: What option(s) do you feel are missing, and how often do you think you'd use them? As others mentioned the list is effectively capped at 5 but we can get the list of migration targets changed if there's a good reason to do so.

Answer (score 8):

We had a lot of arguments over that in past years. ServerFault is unusual in that we have five such targets, but we managed to get them.

The problem at its core is a simple design philosophy:

> Bulleted lists reach the tl;dr limit around 5 items.

Stack as a whole has been trying to keep such often used lists under the 5 limit.

- We have 5 (top level) close reasons
- For a long time, we had 4 migration targets.
- The 'short' lists in the 10K tools view is 3 items.

Necessity gave us the 5th migration target, and the 5th OT reason.

Also, there isn't a big call for a 6th. Our least-used migration target is to DBA, and in the last three months we've sent 10 questions there. SuperUser accepts more questions than the other four targets combined.

Comment: As of today I see 30 questions migrated to DBA, not 10?

Comment: I probably mis-read the 10% rejection rate as the number of migrations.

Answer (score 5):

Most likely no, due to a more or less arbitrary limitation imposed by the SE staff. I can't find relevant discussions right now, but if I remember correctly, there was much debate to even get a fourth migration target instead of the usual three (not counting meta.sf).

Also: I very rarely migrate anything to a site not on the list and for the small number of cases, it's not really relevant IMHO.

Answer (score 3):

As of today we already have the maximum of five migration targets, one of which is meta (this site).

I've actually been watching migration statistics for a while, and four of those five correspond to our most common migration targets.

One of them, however, does not, and hasn't had a post migrated in a very long time, as far as I can recall. That target is, of course, meta.

I would cautiously support replacing that with the next most commonly used migration target, Webmasters, as we get quite a few questions which may be better suited there, far more than are actually migrated since it isn't on the list.

---

I've since been informed that meta is a mandatory migration target and can't be replaced. Oh well, it was a thought.